# Using Web Api 2 authentication, receiving 'No MediaTypeFormatter is available...' error on TokenModel object

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-web-api2

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'TokenModel' from content with media type 'text/html'

I'm receiving the above error when I am making a call to the `/Token` endpoint of Web Api on login. I am using a 2012 `web forms` project as my client and a 2013 `web api 2` project for my api.

I should add that this only happens when I am testing my client from localhost and the api is pushed up to my development server. When I am testing both projects on localhost, the calls work just fine.

If anyone can shed some light on what may be happening, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm going to have people halfway around the world consuming this service in a test scenario, so I need to be able to have it up on my dev server. I appreciate it.

Api call:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(TestServiceUrl);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

            var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("Token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                                            new[]
                                        {
                                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("grant_type","password"),
                                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("username",username),
                                            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("password",password),
                                        }

              ));

            ***vvv line throwing error vvv***
            var tokenModel = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>();

            token = tokenModel.AccessToken;
        }
```

This is the model I'm using for the response message:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Login.Class
{
    public class TokenModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(".expires")]
        public string ExpiresAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(".issued")]
        public string IssuedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("userName")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried adding

`httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-type", "application/json");`

which I found on a developer's blog, but I'm receiving the same error.

Comment: Are you setting the correct `Content-Type` header in the response?

Comment: I was letting it implicitly handle that on its own, which seemed to be acceptable in localhost, but not up on the server.